# Table type null validation

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2017

I have a Guid table type who I declare as:

```
 @MyTableVariable [HELPER].[GuidIdTableType] READONLY
```

For testing propouses I add an empty guid like:

```
INSERT INTO @MyTableVariable (Id) VALUES ('00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000')
```

So I have a  BIT variable who I want to return null if is an empty guid or table is null:

```
  @MyTableVariable [HELPER].[GuidIdTableType] READONLY

  INSERT INTO @MyTableVariable (Id) VALUES ('00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000')


            DECLARE @IsAllSelected BIT = (SELECT TOP 1
                                         1
                                         FROM @MyTableVariable 
                                         WHERE ([Id] = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' 
                                         OR [Id] IS NULL))
         SELECT @IsAllSelected
```

In this case it return 1 because it has empty guid, so that's correct, but if I remove empty guid from script as:

```
 @MyTableVariable [HELPER].[GuidIdTableType] READONLY


                DECLARE @IsAllSelected BIT = (SELECT TOP 1
                                             1
                                             FROM @MyTableVariable 
                                             WHERE ([Id] = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' 
                                             OR [Id] IS NULL))
             SELECT @IsAllSelected
```

It returns null, `WHERE` clause `OR [Id] IS NULL` no work, it's supposed it shoudl returns 1 too because is empty. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are confusing testing a column value for `NULL` with returning a zero row count.  There are no rows to return in  your second example, which is why you are receiving a `NULL` result

Comment: @Martin I understand what you are saying. But if I do something like this:    `DECLARE @MyTableVariable  INT =(SELECT COUNT([Id]) FROM @MyTableVariable)
      IF(@MyTableVariable = 0)
      BEGIN
      INSERT INTO @MyTableVariable(Id) VALUES ('00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000')
      END` . I can't because Table variable is a parameter of my stored procedure so is `READONLY`, how can I solve that case then?

Comment: `DECLARE @IsAllSelected BIT = (SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @MyTableVariable WHERE ID = '0000...') OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @MyTableVariable) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)` should do it. (Disclaimer: not tested.) But you should seriously consider the validity and usefulness of testing for the existence of a an all-zeroes GUID -- what if I pass a table that contains both that GUID, and a bunch of valid ones? Why not just have *one* way of specifying everything should be selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Joren indicated, when recordset returns no rows you will get `NULL` value assigned to the variable.

The way you write this is:

```
DECLARE @IsAllSelected BIT = ISNULL((SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM @MyTableVariable
        WHERE ([Id] = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' OR [Id] IS NULL)), 0 )
```

The variable will be set to 1 when record is found or 0 when record is not found.

Some notes on `TOP 1`:

`TOP 1` ensures that expression will not throw an error if two (or more) rows are returned. Otherwise it is useless in this case.

Another way to do it is using `COUNT(*)` as this will always return a value:

```
DECLARE @IsAllSelected BIT = (SELECT COUNT( * ) FROM @MyTableVariable
        WHERE ([Id] = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' OR [Id] IS NULL))
```